# Tick-labels to span over multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to make the x-tick labels span over two lines?
Say, if my x-tick labels are

```
January 2008, February 2008, March 2008
```

I want them as

```
January  February  March
  2008     2008    2008
```

I don't want to rotate them.

Comment: It seems like it should work if you did `"January\n2008"` as your label (this works in gnuplot for instance), but I don't know matplotlib, so I might just be naive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a quick test using the code I found [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html), it appears that it does indeed work if you just add a newline in your tick label.  e.g.

```
mytics=['January\n2008', 'February\n2008', 'March\n2008']
```